# DialogFlow: why does this Webhook Response fail with 'empty speech response'

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Why does this specific webhook response (passed by DialogFlow back to Google Assistant)

```
    {
      "fulfillmentMessages" : [ {
        "payload" : {
          "google" : {
        "richResponse" : {
          "items" : [ {
            "simpleResponse" : {
              "textToSpeech" : "And are you male or female?"
            }
          } ]
        },
        "expectUserResponse" : true
          }
        },
        "text" : {
          "text" : [ "And are you male or female?" ]
        }
      }, {
        "quickReplies" : {
          "quickReplies" : [ "Male", "Female" ]
        }
      } ],
      "fulfillmentText" : "And are you male or female?",
      "outputContexts" : [ ... ]
    }
```

Error as:

```
"MalformedResponse: Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of Google Assistant, the responses are not part of `fulfillmentMessages` but are in a `payload` object which should be located at the top level of your response.

Note that `quickReplies` and `text` are valid for Dialogflow fulfillment messages but not for Google Assistant too. Instead, you should use `simpleResponse` and `suggestions` fields and put them in the response.

So, for example here is a response for Google Assistant which is made of suggestion chips and a simple response:

```js
{
  payload: {
    google: {
      richResponse: {
        items: [{
          simpleResponse: {
            textToSpeech: "Are you male or female"
          }
        }],
        suggestions: [
          { title: 'Male' },
          { title: 'Female' }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  outputContexts: [...]
}
```

For Dialogflow fulfillment messages (in the Dialogflow console for example), it would have been something like that:

```js
{
  fulfillmentMessages: [
    { text: { text: ['Are you male or female'] } },
    { quickReplies: { quickReplies: ['Male', 'Female'] } } 
  ],
  outputContexts: [...]
}
```

Hope that helps.